# Distribution of (bounded) quiz scores

Tags: probability, distributions, truncated-distributions

Our office does the daily quiz.  Mostly we get around 8/10. We can not go outside the range 0-10, and at both those limits there is a non-zero probability.  What parametric distribution might be appropriate to model this?  Is it just as simple as truncating the non-symmetric distribution that seems to fit best?

Comment: Maybe a generalized beta distribution with support $(0, 10).$ [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Generating_beta-distributed_random_variates) is a place to start for beta distributions on $(0,1);$ then multiply by 10.

Comment: The choice of distribution depends on (1) the reason for doing the modeling and (2) the data.  Without such information, your question is unanswerable.  What can you tell us about those?